# IPython _repr_html_

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I really like how in the IPython Notebook you can add a class method called `_repr_html_()` to print a rich HTML version of your class.

Is there a way to explicitly force this output, say if I want to print 2 objects out at the same time?

```
print obj1, obj2
```

#### Below is solved, but I would still like to know if the above is possible since writing a wrapper is tad tedious

Or, if I have a wrapper class for many of these objects and I want to nest their HTML representation inside the wrapper representation?

```
def _repr_html_(self):
    return '<td>%s</td><td></td>' % (self.obj1, self.obj2)
```

Comment: For the second case, I think you could have the wrapper object concatenate the `_repr_html_` output of the the sub-objects by explicitly doing something like `'<div>%s</div><div>%s</div>' % (self.obj1._repr_html_(), self.obj2._repr_html_())`.

Comment: Thanks!  I would still like to know how to do the first part since writing a wrapper everytime seems a little tedious.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `from IPython.display import display` and call `display` on each or your objects.

Answer (score 2):

For the second case, you can give the wrapper object a `_repr_html_` that explicitly calls `_repr_html_` on its sub-objects and combines them in whatever way you like.

I don't think it's possible to make the first case work, because `_repr_html_` is a `repr`, not a `str` and `str` is used when you `print` an object.  Even if you try to just enter `obj1, obj2` (without the `print`), it won't work, because `obj1, obj2` is a tuple, and a tuple already has its own `repr` that you can't override (nor can you add an `_html_repr_` to the tuple type).

Here's a simple example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
    def _repr_html_(self):
        return "<p><em>This is the <strong>{0}</strong> object</em>!</p>".format(self.value)

class Wrapper(object):
    def __init__(self, foo1, foo2):
        self.foo1 = foo1
        self.foo2 = foo2

    def _repr_html_(self):
        return """
        <h3>Foo1</h3>
        {0}
        <h3>Foo2</h3>
        {1}
        """.format(self.foo1._repr_html_(), self.foo2._repr_html_())
```

With these classes, doing `Foo("Blah")` will work, and creating two `Foo` objects and wrapping them with a `Wrapper` will work.  But just entering `foo1, foo2` (where those are Foo object) won't work, for the reason I described above.  If you want to HTML-display multiple objects, you'll have to explicitly wrap them with a wrapper class that has its own `_repr_html_`.  (Of course, you could give this wrapper class a short name like `HTML` or `show` or whatever, so you can just do `show(obj1, obj2)`.)